# Could not parse DTD

Tags: xml, database, markdown, dtd

I am doing an exercise for an online course.. and I am stuck on an exercise. I get the following from xmllint:

```
/tmp/tmpYQmAtj.dtd:8: parser error : expected '>'
<!ATTLIST Course Instructors IDREFS #REQUIRED>
^
Could not parse DTD /tmp/tmpYQmAtj.dtd
```

Here is a part of the xml file which I am trying to describe:

```
<Course Number="CS124" Prerequisites="CS107 CS109" Instructors="DJ" Enrollment="60">
```

The IDREFS refers to the IDs stated below:

```
<Professor InstrID="DJ">
    <First_Name>Dan</First_Name>
    <Last_Name>Jurafsky</Last_Name>
</Professor>
```

In my DTD, I have described this as follows:

```
<!ATTLIST Professor InstrID ID #REQUIRED>
```

So then, if I have (1) defined the ID, (2) pointed to the ID using IDREFS, why am I getting this error?!!!?

Comment: What does the line look like above the ATTLIST mentioned in the error (should be line 7)? Are you missing a `>` like the error mentions?

Comment: You're getting the error because there is an error in the part of the DTD you didn't show us.  The DTD parser notices the error when it sees the beginning of the next declaration, but the error is (as Daniel Haley has already point out) in the material before the ATTLIST you show.

Comment: Oh wowwww. Man that was embarrassing of me. You guys were right..